# How to get an access token to read messages on Discord via API?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I would like to use the Discord API to read messages from different servers (e.g., StableDiffusion).

I created a bot via the developer page: https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and I was able to make a basic REST call:

```py
import requests

headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {public_key}"}
url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/v9/users/@me'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
response.json()
```

Unfortunately, I get 403 errors when trying to read messages from StableDiffusion:

```py
import requests

headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {public_key}"}
url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/1002292398703001601/messages?limit=50'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.json()
```

> {'message': 'Missing Access', 'code': 50001}

Where or how do I get the access token? Are there special permissions needed for the bot?

I selected the `Administrator` option under "General Permissions", which presumably enables everything.

My general account is already authorized to read messages from that Server; do those permissions transfer over to my bot?

Comment: Not sure how you do that in Discord.py, but you need to enable intents because that's required when reading messages and the content of these messages. Also, when you create your bot, you'll be able to create a private token. Your public token is, if I'm correct, used for OAuth2 purposes. Assuming you have the private token, double check if you have enabled all intents on the developer console as well. I have no experience using Python, so I have no idea how you have to pass the intents in the REST calls.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

I'm using the private token generated in the Bot tab of the developers page.

I've also enabled all the "Privileged Gateway Intents" listed on that page, which include: "PRESENCE INTENT", "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT", and "MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT". 

Do I have to add additional permissions to the Bot to read servers that are not owned by me?